# Prevent plugins loading on all pages (Next-gen Gallery)

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

Is it possible to prevent Next-gen Gallery from loading on all requests?

I am including WP into vBulletin using the proper WP method:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/home/username/public_html/wp-blog-header.php');
```

For the most part it works but Next-gen gallery is throwing lots of errors:

```
    Warning: Declaration of M_Ajax::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ajax/module.ajax.php on line 99

    Warning: Declaration of M_Attach_To_Post::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/attach_to_post/module.attach_to_post.php on line 415

    Warning: Declaration of M_Cache::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/cache/module.cache.php on line 39

    Warning: Declaration of M_DataMapper::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/datamapper/module.datamapper.php on line 250

    Warning: Declaration of M_Dynamic_Stylesheet::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/dynamic_stylesheet/module.dynamic_stylesheet.php on line 66

    Warning: Declaration of M_Dynamic_Thumbnails::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/dynamic_thumbnails/module.dynamic_thumbnails.php on line 67

    Warning: Declaration of M_Frame_Communication::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/frame_communication/module.frame_communication.php on line 67

    Warning: Declaration of M_Fs::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/fs/module.fs.php on line 33

    Warning: Declaration of M_I18N::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/i18n/module.i18n.php on line 250

    Warning: Declaration of M_Lightbox::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/module.lightbox.php on line 54

    Warning: Declaration of M_MediaRss::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/mediarss/module.mediarss.php on line 55

    Warning: Declaration of M_MVC::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/mvc/module.mvc.php on line 69

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_AddGallery_Page::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_addgallery_page/module.nextgen_addgallery_page.php on line 78

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Admin::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_admin/module.nextgen_admin.php on line 166

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Basic_Album::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_album/module.nextgen_basic_album.php on line 162

    Warning: Declaration of C_NextGen_Basic_Album_Installer::install() should be compatible with C_Gallery_Display_Installer::install($reset = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_album/module.nextgen_basic_album.php on line 186

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Basic_Gallery::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_gallery/module.nextgen_basic_gallery.php on line 265

    Warning: Declaration of C_NextGen_Basic_Gallery_Installer::install() should be compatible with C_Gallery_Display_Installer::install($reset = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_gallery/module.nextgen_basic_gallery.php on line 341

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Basic_ImageBrowser::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_imagebrowser/module.nextgen_basic_imagebrowser.php on line 132

    Warning: Declaration of C_NextGen_Basic_ImageBrowser_Installer::install() should be compatible with C_Gallery_Display_Installer::install($reset = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_imagebrowser/module.nextgen_basic_imagebrowser.php on line 182

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Basic_Singlepic::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_singlepic/module.nextgen_basic_singlepic.php on line 132

    Warning: Declaration of C_NextGen_Basic_SinglePic_Installer::install() should be compatible with C_Gallery_Display_Installer::install($reset = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_singlepic/module.nextgen_basic_singlepic.php on line 148

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Basic_Tagcloud::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_tagcloud/module.nextgen_basic_tagcloud.php on line 152

    Warning: Declaration of C_NextGen_Basic_Tagcloud_Installer::install() should be compatible with C_Gallery_Display_Installer::install($reset = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_tagcloud/module.nextgen_basic_tagcloud.php on line 172

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Basic_Templates::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_templates/module.nextgen_basic_templates.php on line 49

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Data::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_data/module.nextgen_data.php on line 106

    Warning: Declaration of M_Gallery_Display::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_gallery_display/module.nextgen_gallery_display.php on line 442

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Other_Options::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_other_options/module.nextgen_other_options.php on line 168

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Pagination::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_pagination/module.nextgen_pagination.php on line 28

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Pro_Upgrade::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_pro_upgrade/module.nextgen_pro_upgrade.php on line 42

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_Settings::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_settings/module.nextgen_settings.php on line 35

    Warning: Declaration of M_NextGen_XmlRpc::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_xmlrpc/module.nextgen_xmlrpc.php on line 662

    Warning: Declaration of M_NggLegacy::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ngglegacy/module.ngglegacy.php on line 49

    Warning: Declaration of M_Router::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/router/module.router.php on line 46

    Warning: Declaration of M_Security::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/security/module.security.php on line 51

    Warning: Declaration of M_Third_Party_Compat::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/third_party_compat/module.third_party_compat.php on line 496

    Warning: Declaration of M_Validation::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/validation/module.validation.php on line 30

    Warning: Declaration of M_Widget::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/widget/module.widget.php on line 53

    Warning: Declaration of M_WordPress_Routing::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/wordpress_routing/module.wordpress_routing.php on line 80

    Warning: Declaration of M_WPCLI::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Module::define($id = 'pope-modul...', $name = 'Pope Modul...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/wpcli/module.wpcli.php on line 32

    Warning: Declaration of P_Photocrati_NextGen::define() should be compatible with C_Base_Product::define($id = 'pope-produ...', $name = 'Pope Produ...', $description = '', $version = '', $uri = '', $author = '', $author_uri = '', $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/product.photocrati_nextgen.php on line 108

    Warning: Declaration of C_Http_Response_Controller::define() should be compatible with C_Component::define($context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/router/package.module.router.php on line 25

    Warning: Declaration of C_MVC_View::define() should be compatible with C_Component::define($context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/mvc/package.module.mvc.php on line 412

    Warning: Declaration of C_MVC_View::initialize() should be compatible with C_Component::initialize() in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/mvc/package.module.mvc.php on line 412

    Warning: Declaration of C_Gallery::define() should be compatible with C_DataMapper_Model::define($mapper = NULL, $properties = Array, $context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_data/package.module.nextgen_data.php on line 288

    Warning: Declaration of C_Gallery_Storage::define() should be compatible with C_Component::define($context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_data/package.module.nextgen_data.php on line 510

    Warning: Declaration of C_GalleryStorage_Driver_Base::define() should be compatible with C_Component::define($context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_data/package.module.nextgen_data.php on line 1734

    Warning: Declaration of C_Form::define() should be compatible with C_MVC_Controller::define($context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_admin/package.module.nextgen_admin.php on line 221

    Warning: Declaration of C_Attach_Controller::define() should be compatible with C_NextGen_Admin_Page_Controller::define($context = false) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/attach_to_post/package.module.attach_to_post.php on line 279

    Warning: Declaration of C_Settings_Model::__get() should be compatible with & ExtensibleObject::__get($property) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_other_options/package.module.nextgen_other_options.php on line 675

    Warning: Declaration of C_Settings_Model::__set() should be compatible with & ExtensibleObject::__set($property, $value) in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_other_options/package.module.nextgen_other_options.php on line 675

    Warning: Redefining already defined constructor for class nggdb in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ngglegacy/lib/ngg-db.php on line 59

    Warning: Redefining already defined constructor for class nggPostThumbnail in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ngglegacy/lib/post-thumbnail.php on line 26
```

It is only this plugin causing the problems, is there a way to stop it from loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I hate answers like this, but there are a bunch of plugins that achieve this sort of thing: [Plugin Load Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-load-filter/), [Disable Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-plugins/), [Plugin Logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-logic/), [Plugin Organizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried a few plugins that prevent excess loading of other plugins and they didn't really work.. 'Plugin Logic' totally killed it dead, it now only runs on the gallery pages which is perfect. No errors on external pages and i've noticed site speed improvements as well. Best plugin ever!

Comment: I agree, Plugin Logic is the easiest to use out of the bunch!